# Django - use different views.py for two different domain names?

Tags: django, url-routing

I have two sites that share the same models.py and admin backend, but use different views.py and different template files.

Is there a way to get Django to use a different views.py file for each of the two domain names?  Could I look at the request.HTTP_HOST in some sort of a custom middleware?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To expand a bit on @jdi's answer. The Sites framework is made for this purpose in Django, but you need to serve each domain separately to take advantage of it. What you do is create a separate settings.py file for each domain. You can still have a common settings.py that each includes though. For example:

### settings.py

```
# all common settings here
```

### domain1_settings.py

```
from settings import *

SITE_ID = 1
ROOT_URLCONF = domain1_urls.py
```

### domain2_settings.py

```
from settings import *

SITE_ID = 2
ROOT_URLCONF = domain2_urls.py
```

Then, you manually specify which settings file to use when you start the server:

### development

```
python manage.py runserver --settings=domain1_settings.py
```

### production (gunicorn)

```
python manage.py run_gunicorn --settings=domain1_settings.py
```

### production (uwsgi)

```
uwsgi --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.domain1_settings
```

Obviously, you would more likely want to include that in the actual configuration for gunicorn/uwsgi; the above is just for illustrative purposes.

Comment: Nice organization of this information. Really does expand on what I was saying quite well.

Comment: this is essentially how we do it at my job: settings.py file for the main site (domain.com), mobile_settings.py for the mobile site (m.domain.com). 2 uwsgi instances each pointing at one of the settings files. the only thing we do differently is have an app named "mobile" in our project and add that ONLY in the mobile_settings.py's INSTALLED_APPS, with the ROOT_URLCONF pointing at 'mobile.urls'.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is the purpose of the Sites framework in django:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/sites/

You define sites, and have facilities to check this in you project.

Comment: This is what Sites is for, *but* Sites expects you to serve each domain on a separate Django instance with a unique settings.py. Specifically, you need to set `SITE_ID` uniquely in each settings.py.

Comment: @ChrisPratt: but then you go and post an answer also suggesting a solution that requires separate instances ;-)

Comment: I wasn't disagreeing with you. I was just pointing out the fact that you need separate instances to use Sites. After adding the comment, I realized it deserve more description.

Comment: @ChrisPratt: LOL, I totally confused you with being Chris W. I had said this before you even posted an answer. I'm silly like that.

Answer (score 0):

The `Sites` framework that @jdi mentioned is probably what you're looking for although it may require you to integrate the `django.contrib.sites.models.Site` model into your current models.

Another option would be if you already have (or plan on having) your two Django sites running in two different server processes then you might consider associating two different `settings.py` files with each process. Each `settings.py` file would be essentially the same except reference different `urls.py` files which would in turn reference different `views.py` files.

This solution might be better if you see these two sites diverging more in the future.